# Retrieve posts from facebook private group where I am a member of

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Based on my understanding about Facebook Graph API, it sounds like this is not possible,
but I'll ask anyway in case there's some other API or stuff that I don't know of. I figured since I can see it on a website anyway, maybe it's possible to read it programmatically with facebook api, or write a scraper or other things.

Is it possible to retrieve all new posts from a private group where I'm a member of (not admin)?

Use case, I'd like to create a script where if there's new posts with some keyword that I set up, it will send me some kind of notification or message.

Comment: No it is not possible